# javascript terms for functions for registration form

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML registration page with a series of JavaScript validation functions. I want to add a condition that if all of the functions validate correctly => do something else. I want to make it so that I can run all of the validation functions inside a single function.

```
function UserName()
{
    var User = register.Username.value;
    var i;

    if (User.length == 0)
        alert("Please Enter First name");

    else if (User.length < 6) 
        alert("your name most have a minimum of 6 digits/charachters");    
}

function Passw() {
    var Pass = register.password.value;
    var SCharCount = 0;
    var LCharCount = 0;
    var NCount = 0;
    var special = 0;
    var i;

    if (Pass == "")
        alert("Please enter a Password");


    else if (Pass.length > 5 && Pass.length < 15) {
        for (i = 0; i < Pass.length; i++) {
            if ((Pass.charAt(i) >= 'a') && (Pass.charAt(i) <= 'z'))
                SCharCount++;

            else if ((Pass.charAt(i) >= 'A') && (Pass.charAt(i) <= 'Z'))
                LCharCount++;

            else if ((Pass.charAt(i) >= '0') && (Pass.charAt(i) <= '9'))
                NCount++;

            else if ((Pass.charAt(i) >= '!') && (Pass.charAt(i) <= '?'))
                special++;
         }
     }

     if ((SCharCount==0) || (LCharCount==0) || (NCount == 0) || (special==0)) {
         alert("Your password weak please notes that you most have at least 5-15 digits providen by one of each keys :1-9 , !-? , a-z , A-Z");
     }

     else
         return true;
}

function ConfPassw() {
    var Pass = register.password.value;
    var CPass = register.Confirm_password.value;

    if (Pass != CPass) {
        alert("the password must match");
    }

}

function FirstName() {
    var Fname = register.Input_Your_Name.value;

    if (Fname.length == 0) {
         alert("Enter First Name");
    }
}

function Lastname() {
    var Lname = register.Input_Your_Name.value;

    if (Lname.length == 0) {
        alert("Enter Last Name");
    }
}

function CountryColumn() {
     var Country = register.Country.value;
     var Count = 0;
     var i;

     if (Country.length == 0)
         alert("Country not found");
     else
         for (i = 0; i < Country.length; i++) {        
             if ((Country.charAt(i) >= '0') && (Country.charAt(i) <= '9'))
                 Count++;
         }

     if (Count > 0) 
         alert("Country cannot contain a Number");
     else    
         return true;
 }                                                         

function address() {              
    var Addr = register.Address.value;
    if (Addr.length == 0) 
        alert("Enter Address");
}   

function poscode() {
    var code=register.Input_postalcode.value;   
    if (code.length == 0) 
        alert("Enter a postal code");
}

function PhoneN() {
    var phone = register.Phone_Number.value;
    var phone_num = isNaN(phone);

    if (phone.length == 0)
        alert("you must include your phone in the registration");
    if (phone_num)
        alert("This Should contain Only Digits");
    else if (phone.charAt(0) == 0 && phone.charAt(1) == 2 && phone.length == 9)
        return true;
    else if (phone.charAt(0) == 0 && phone.charAt(1) == 5 && phone.length == 10)
        return true;
    else
        alert("Wrong Telephone/Mobile Number please notes that we only support home telephone with 02 in the beggining and only israel mobile numbers that start with 05X")  
}

function Mail() {
    var mail = register.Input_email.value;
    var lastApos = mail.lastIndexOf('@');
    var lastDotPos = mail.lastIndexOf('.');

    if (mail.length == 0) 
        alert("Please enter your Email");
    else if (!(lastApos < lastDotPos && lastApos > 0 && mail.indexOf('@@') == -1 && (mail.length - lastDotPos) > 2))
        alert("The Email was write in wrong way");
    else if (lastDotPos - mail.indexOf('@') > 2)
        return true;
    else
        alert("The Email was write in wrong way");
}

function date() {
    var day = register.Date_of_birth_Day.value;
    var month = register.Date_of_birth_Month.value;
    var year = register.Date_of_birth_Year.value;

    if (day == '-') {
        alert("select the day your born");
    }

    if (month == '-') {
        alert("select the month your born");
    }

    if (year == '-') {
        alert("select the year your born");
    }
}

function gender() {
    if (register.Gender[0].checked == false && register.Gender[1].checked == false) {
        alert("Choose your gender wierdo");
    }
}

function DataConfirnation() {
    UserName();
    Passw();
    ConfPassw();
    FirstName();
    Lastname();
    address();
    poscode();
    PhoneN();
    Mail();
    date();
    gender();
    CountryColumn();
}
```

Comment: can you revise your question? I don't understand it. What are you trying to ask?

Comment: I'm unsure what you are asking, do you wan to run all the functions at once? Also, please fix your code formatting.

Comment: look i got registration page in html and on that page i have some javascript function that valid the data that user put inside, now i want to make a term that if all the functions is run correctly it gonna provide me to other html page with saying the registration complete or something like that.   and i dont have a idea how make the term

Comment: @MrBonggMrBong Have all functions return `true` and check that if they all return true, go to your registration complete webpage.

Comment: some explanation , i mean i know what you mean in boolian varriable but i dont actually get the idea how to make it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you will want to do is have each function return a Boolean based on is the values for that item are invalid or valid. For invalid input `return false` and for valid input `return true`. Here is a simple example with two functions:

```
function validateOne() {
    if( /* Input for validateOne is valid */ )
        return true
    else
        return false
}

function validateTwo() {
    if( /* Input for validateTwo is valid */ )
        return true
    else
        return false
}

if(validateOne() && validateTwo()) {
    // Everything is valid, move to registration complete webpage
} else {
    // Not everything is valid
}
```

Here a real example using the concepts above for verifying say a username and a password. Where (for simplicity) the username cannot be empty and the password cannot be empty and needs to be more than 5 characters. Your program overall will be a little more complex from this.

```
function validateUsername() {
    // When there is at least a single character entered
    var username = register.Username.value;
    if( username.length > 0 ) 
        return true; // than the username is valid
    else
        return false; // otherwise not valid
}

function validatePassword() {
    // When the length of the password is over 5
    var password = register.password.value; 
    if( password.length > 5 )
        return true; // than the password is valid
    else
        return false; // otherwise not valid
}

if(validateUsername() && validatePassword()) {
    // Everything is valid, move to registration complete webpage
} else {
    // Not everything is valid
}
```

To get you started here is how your first `Username` function would look:

```
function UserName()
{
    var User = register.Username.value;
    //var i; <- You don't need this

    if (User.length == 0) { // cannot be empty -> false
        alert("Please Enter First name");
        return false;
    }
    else if (User.length < 6) { // Needs more than 6 characters -> false
        alert("your name most have a minimum of 6 digits/charachters"); 
        return false;
    }
    else { // Has more than 6 characters -> true
        return true;
   }      
}
```

Comment: exacly but how i check if the function is valid or invalid (done or not done yet)

Comment: For example in `UserName()` the first two `if` and `else if` would return false, and adding an `else` that returns `true`(being that it's more than 6 in length).

Comment: man i mean what i need to put here if( /* here */ ) what kind of term

Comment: the last thing i want to ask can i add in a condition(term) like in html href that if the condition is executed it gonna provide me to another page in javascript . thank you a lot for all the help.

Comment: @MrBonggMrBong I'm not sure what you mean, do you mean how do you go to another page in JavaScript? The condition would be all your functions returning true.

Comment: not exacly , how java will provide me to another webpage if the all the condition return true;  * you know because i can't put a <a href> in javascript.

Comment: @MrBonggMrBong You can use `window.location.href = "www.google.com";`. Setting `window.location.href` moves to a new page.